# How can I simultaneously read and write a file in S3?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, cloud

I'm planning to create a podcast app in Java using S3. I plan to have my audio be placed in S3, live, as I talk while also letting users be able to listen to the audio while I'm talking.

I've searched through documentation but can't seem to find any concrete info on if this is possible, and if so how.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for disaster. Why not use a real streaming service, and then just upload the file to S3 when you're done? What problem are you trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: The live component is a crucial component of the app. Without going into too much detail, the plan is to build on top of this in a unique collaborative way with longer podcasts.

Why exactly would this be a disaster? Genuinely curious since I've never had this type of problem before.

Comment: I say it sounds like a recipe for disaster because this isn't what S3 was designed to do. It's not a streaming service, it's a file storage service. I'd highly recommend revisiting your plan and considering using a streaming service instead.

Comment: Hm, that makes sense. I might have gotten my wires crossed with the different services and thought it was possible. For example, CloudFront http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/ which I thought integrated with S3 but maybe not.

Comment: Cloudfront will stream a file from s3, provided the entire object exists on s3. To do live streaming, you need to do use a different origin.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon S3 can be used to stream content out, but the object must be there and complete. It's not possible to stream content into S3.

When adding or updating an object in S3, the object is not available to be read until the upload (add or update) is complete.

Comment: Almost totally correct.  It *is* technically possible to stream content into S3... but it doesn't matter, because writes in S3 are always atomic, so until the stream is *done*, the object still can't be read.  Although the consistency model varies by region and, in some cases, depends on whether its a new object or an overwrite, in all cases, until the write is completely finished, the object can't be read. (So, +1).

Answer (score 0):

S3 is not a good solution for this application. S3 only provides eventual consistency in US Standard, and read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects in other regions. You cannot stream a file into S3 and have it erad like a conventional filesystem.

The better option would be to upload and stream from an EC2 instance to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. So this is EC2 instead of S3, and not in conjunction, correct?